# Conformers with extremely high energy barriers?

Tags: conformers

What are some conformers with very high energy barriers? When we think of e.g. the butane conformers, at room temperature, the conformational change plays almost no role. I was wondering how molecules look like that are almost exclusively in one energy valley **or** the other (so something like 50-50, not 99-1) and hence might even have different physical properties, depending on the conformation it is in.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropisomer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Googling for "conformer with high energy barrier" and similar didn't lead me to the atropisomers. Only thing is that the examples on Wikipedia don't have spectacularly different forms/physical properties but are extremely similar.